# Template renders before promise is completed

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, promise, firebase-authentication

I am trying to implement persistent sign sessions for a website using firebase. I believe I have done everything correctly except when the user reloads the page, the authentication tokens are available but because my **function fetchAuthTokenOnReload() has a promise** inside it (I believe that's where the problem is), that promise gets resolved only after my HTML has already been rendered on by the browser. I know this because after a reload, I'm initially signed out but as soon as I click something like a random button that causes a re-render, I'm signed in.

This is weird because I don't get this problem with Observables. I tried looking around on how to handle promises and how or how to convert Promises to Observables but to no success. I also tried to re-route the user after the promise is complete since that would cause a re-render but it didn't work.
Also weird because my firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password) function uses a promise too but I don't problems after signing int.

Any help is appreciated.

*auth.service.ts*

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { ConfirmationModalService } from '../confirmation-modal/confirmation-modal.service';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {

  token: String;
  tokenChanged = new Subject<String>();

  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private confirmationModalService: ConfirmationModalService) { }

  signInUser(email: string, password: string) {
    firebase
      .auth()
      .setPersistence(firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.LOCAL)
      .then(() => {
        return firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
          .then( // also uses a promise but no problems here
            response => {
              this.router.navigate(['/']);
              firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken()
                .then(
                  (token: string) => {
                    this.token = token;
                    this.tokenChanged.next(token);
                  }
                );
            }
          )
          .catch(
            error => {
              console.log(error);
              this.confirmationModalService.displayConfirmationModal('invalid username/password', 'failure', 2000);
            }
          );
      }).catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }

  setAuthToken(token: String) {
    console.log('setting auth token');
    this.token = token;
    this.tokenChanged.next(token);
    console.log('set autToken');
  }

  getAuthToken() {
    return this.token;
  }

  fetchAuthTokenOnReload() {
    console.log('fetchAuthTokenOnReload()');
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      console.log(this.token);
      if (user) {
        console.log('already signed in');
        console.log('currently authToken = user.getIdToken()');
        return user.getIdToken()
          .then((token) => {
            this.setAuthToken(token);
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
          });
      } else {
        console.log('not signed in');
        console.log(user);
        return null;
      }
    });
  }

  logout() {
    firebase.auth().signOut();
    this.token = null;
    this.tokenChanged.next(null);
    window.location.reload();
  }


**app.component.ts**


    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { Router, NavigationEnd } from '@angular/router';
    import * as firebase from 'firebase';
    import { AuthService } from './auth/auth.service';
    import { AngularFireStorage } from 'angularfire2/storage';

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-root',
      templateUrl: './app.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
    })

    export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

      token: String;
      isAuthenticated: boolean;

      constructor(
        private router: Router,
        private authService: AuthService,
        private afStorage: AngularFireStorage) {
        this.router.events.subscribe(event => {
          if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
            (<any>window).ga('set', 'page', event.urlAfterRedirects);
            (<any>window).ga('send', 'pageview');
          }
        });
      }

      ngOnInit() {
        this.authTokenChanged();
        this.authService.fetchAuthTokenOnReload();
      }

      // When the pages has finished loading, this.token has the correct value but the browser uses the previous value, which is undefined at the time

      authTokenChanged() {
        console.log('inside observable authTokenChaned()');
        console.log('authTokenChanged() - before change');
        console.log(this.token);
        this.authService.tokenChanged.subscribe(
          (token) => {
            this.token = token;
            console.log('authTokenChanged() - after change');
            console.log(this.token);
            this.router.navigate(['/']);
          }
        );
      }
    }
```

*app.component.html*

```
<div *ngIf="token">
  <div class="auth-status-bar logged-in">YOU ARE LOGGED IN</div>
</div>

<app-confirmation-modal></app-confirmation-modal>
<div class="container-fluid row">
  <div class="col-xs-12" [ngStyle]="{ 'margin-top': token ? '30px' : '0px' }">
    <app-header></app-header>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    <router-outlet name='opportunities'></router-outlet>
    <app-footer></app-footer>
  </div>
</div>
```

What should happen is: After reloading the page, this div:

```
<div *ngIf="token">
  <div class="auth-status-bar logged-in">YOU ARE LOGGED IN</div>
</div>
```

should show.

Comment: Why do you navigate to `/` here even before getting `token`: `.then( response => { this.router.navigate(['/']);` ?

Comment: Actually didn't give that any thought since that piece of code was present before I started working on this. It worked as intended so I didn't touch it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use BehaviorSubject rather than using Subject at the place of tokenChanged, as Subject doesn’t hold the value and that’s why you are getting as null.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. But even with BehaviorSubject the promise doesn't complete on time. I changed tokenChanged = new Subject<String>(); to tokenChanged = new BehaviorSubject<String>(null); in authService.ts but the template still uses null as the token.